# HTML Onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to do an onclick to a function I have to pass a variable and test that it works.  I have the onclick hooked to a button.

To make sure the function is working I just added the function call before the button and it work fine....when i click on the button however I see an error reported in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myController is not defined

Here is the sample block

```
   fileNameFormatter : function(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext, grid) {
            var file = null;
            myController.SubmitVal(value); -->> THIS WORKS!!!!!
            file = '<button onclick="myController.SubmitVal(\'' + value + '\')" type="button">Submit</button>'; -->> THIS FAILS!!!!
            return file;            
           }, 


    SubmitVal : function(value){   
        alert("submit button pressed: " + value);
    },
```

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: Maybe it's a scope problem. `myController` is available in the window scope?

Comment: _"THIS FAILS!!!!"_ Do you see an error logged in your browser console? (press F12)

Comment: It says "myController is not defined"...I said that in my description

Comment: @DocHoliday Not explicitly in a way that refers to the actual variables in the code :)  I've edited your question - hope that's ok, feel free to change if not!

Comment: Add more info and relevant code... how is `myController` function declared... What you do with `fileNameFormatter` return code (the button)..  Can you provide a working example (or at least the full related code).  The problem you have is related to code that are not shown.

Comment: Where is `myController` declared? I think @GustavoStraube may be onto the root problem being a scoping issue.

Comment: Yep the issue was the controller scope I had it initialed to null at the top and then in init I was setting it